# xsl:value-of select item in list?

Tags: xslt

apologies, not sure what this is called but I need to select the value for "City" in the xml I have below and have not found a solution.

```
 <editorial>
    <group>
    <article>
            <item name="Last Name">DOE</item>
            <item name="First Name">John E. (Skip)</item>
            <item name="Age">80</item>
            <item name="City">Pawtucket</item>
            <item name="State"></item>
            <item name="Formerly Of"></item>
            <item name="Death Date">1/11</item>
    </article>
    </group>
    </editorial>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: I meant where exactly are you stuck with your problem? Post your attempt so we can fix it. -- P.S. This site has a help section.

Comment: thanks, I apologize, nevermind.

Comment: answer is <xsl:value-of select="/editorial/group/article/item[4]"></xsl:value-of>

Comment: Another answer would be `<xsl:value-of select="/editorial/group/article/item[@name='City']">` as that would work even if the items were in a different order.